# IBM speech to text using w4a format audio (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Im trying to use IBM speech to text API to transcript the audio in messenger to text script.

```
request({
        uri: attachment.url,
        method: 'GET',
        encoding: null
      }, (err, res, audio) => {... do something...}
```

I use request to get the audio file from the url I get in message.
But I can only get w4a file, Watson only supports

> audio/flac
>
> audio/wav
>
> audio/l16
>
> audio/ogg

How do I convert w4a format audio to wav to fit the spec.

Or there exists other way to do that?

thanks.

Comment: The keywords to look for are "nodejs" and "ffmpeg". Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725893/how-do-you-use-node-js-to-stream-an-mp4-file-with-ffmpeg

Comment: It is actually a watson question, so we need to add watson tag to get the right attention

Comment: this is really a question about audio conversion, the audio formats supported by the Watson STT service are listed here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/input.html note that webm is also supported

Answer (score 2):

Use a package like [audiobuffer-to-wav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiobuffer-to-wav) to convert your source audio file(.w4a) to Watson STT compatible format like mp3/wav, then use the converted file with Watson STT API. And, If you need to use this library server side, you can emulate AudioContext functionality with web-audio-api package.